# как проигнорировать искажения в последовательностях?

Tags: алгоритм

Даны два битовых потока, отличающиеся друг от друга не более, чем на k бит.

Как проигнорировать незначительные искажения, и посчитать эти потоки одинаковыми?

Comment: Последовательности чего даны? Что означает, что они отличаются k битами? Сортированы ли последовательности или нет?

Comment: битовые последовательности. одинаковые, за исключением k битов

Comment: Что такое "битовая последовательность"? Как вы ее определяете в рамках языка C++? При этом непонятно, имеют ли они одинаковую длину или нет? Это скорей всего вопрос не по C++, а по алгоритмам.

Comment: Сравнивать побитово, и если найдется k+1 пара неодинаковых битов, тогда считать последовательности неодинаковыми

Comment: Допустима ли разная длина потоков?
В любом случае, сравнивать побитово. После первой же найденной разницы начинается "жадный" поиск наиболее длинных одинаковых кусков в оставшихся хвостах: что считать ошибкой и в каком из потоков, с тем, чтобы максимизировать совпадения. Вероятно, это NP-полная задача.

Comment: [Похожий вопрос](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/579981/calculating-binary-data-similarity) (на англ.). Можно ли говорить о сравнении двух бинарных файлов, в содержании которых возможны замены, вставки и удаления фрагментов – и определении меры этих изменений?

Answer (score 1):

Ну а в чём сложность? Вот набросок:

```
unsigned int bit_count(unsigned int v) // Kerrighan way
{
    unsigned int accum;
    for (accum = 0; v; accum++)
        v &= v - 1;
    return accum;
}

bool compare(seq s1, seq s2, unsigned int ignore_bits)
{
    unsigned int rest_bits = ignore_bits;
    while (!s1.finished() || s2.finished())
    {
        unsigned int curr1 = s1.current_int(), curr2 = s2.current_int();
        unsigned int diff = curr1 ^ curr2;
        unsigned int different_bits = bit_count(diff);
        if (different_bits > rest_bits)
            return false;
        rest_bits -= different_bits;
    }
    return s1.finished() && s2.finished();
}
```

---

Решение может отличаться в зависимости от того, как вы хотите интерпретировать последовательности разной длины. Отбрасывать хвост? Считать недостающие биты нулями? Считать недостающие биты несовпадающими?

---

В решении используется неопределённый тип `seq`, представляющий битовую последовательность. Если вы уточните свой тип, можно будет уточнить и решение.

Comment: Поставивший минус, надеюсь, не сочтёт за труд объяснить свою отметку?

Comment: По ключевым словам "не более чем на k битов" видно, что это - сильно перевранный вопрос из теории помехоустойчивого кодирования. А в вашем коде помехоустойчивого кодирования нет... Впрочем, это может быть и попытка создания помехоустойчивой хеш-функции. Или чем-то еще. Странно видеть столь конкретный ответ на абсолютно непонятный вопрос.

Comment: PS настолько странно мне это видеть в час ночи, было бы сейчас утро - я бы по минусу случайно не кликнул :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну, вопрос-то звучал однозначно: _Даны два битовых потока_. Помехоустойчивое кодирование — это «дан ОДИН поток».

Comment: @VladD, насколько я понимаю, это решение может сравнивать только строки одинаковой длины? По сути мы смотрим на разницу, которая возникает  при замене бита и совершенно не учитываем вставки-удаления.  В принципе я задумался, что тут можно посмотреть и по другому, т.е. так, как в утилите diff. Но,  конечно, задача совершенно неопределенно сформулирована.

Comment: @avp: да, про неравные по длине «строки» оно сообщает, что они не равны. В принципе, можно дописать логику, начиная от конца `while`.

Comment: @VladD, основная мысль это -- строки одинаково выровнены и k бит изменены. Это ведь здорово отличается от, скажем, одинаковых, но циклически сдвинутых на 1 бит строк. И алгоритм, заложенный в diff (как мне кажется) скажет, что у сдвинутых строк различие минимально.

Comment: @avp: Угу, у diff'а задача намного сложнее. Он наверное _оценивает_ несхожесть строк, и при слишком большой начинает искать вперёд.

Comment: @VladD, в вике пишут, что [diff](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) основана на поиске *наибольшей общей последовательности* к которой затем применяют операции удаления и вставки.

Comment: @avp: И судя по всему самая алгоритмически сложная часть — это нахождение [наибольшей подпоследовательности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C).

Comment: @VladD, наверняка (думаю, особенно мучительно для битовых строк).